# right-justified column and bold-face rows

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I'm new to latex but I'm trying to learn and am piecing together various pieces of code from different postings, so I apologize if this code is "messy".

In a table, I would like to have the widths of the columns custom-defined, and I would also like to make specific rows bold. I had found out from another posting how to make specific rows bold, but now when I add code to make my column custom-width and right-justified, the bold-faced row part doesn't work anymore. Here is an example, where you see both situations:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%for adding the ability to make entire rows bold:
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

%define right justified column with custom width
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{tabular}{$p{2.1cm} ^p{1.6cm} R{1.5cm} R{2cm}}
\hline
header1 & header2 & header3 & header4\\
\hline
a & b & c & d\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
e & f & g & h\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, when I use the raggedleft column type (to make it right-justified), the bold-face doesn't work.

Any ideas as to how I can get these two to work together?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the `\currentrowstyle` in the `R` column type:

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\currentrowstyle\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Making this change yields the complete row in bold:

[image]